# Append a subset of a queryset to the same queryset (not logical union)

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

if I do:

```
all_queryset = Person.objects.all()
all_queryset.count() # --> 8

subset_queryset = Person.object.filter(name = 'John')
subset_queryset.count() # --> 1
```

Let's say I want to append the `subset_queryset` to the `all_queryset` (even keeping duplicates):

```
result_qs = all_queryset.union(subset_queryset)
result_qs.count()  # STILL 8!
# or
all_queryset |= subset_queryset
all_queryset.count() # STILL 8!
```

I get it's really a LOGICAL union in a sense of: if it's a subset of a more global queryset, it keeps the global. (the opposite of logical intersection qith `&`).

Comment: union will get optional parameter `all` [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union)  `result_qs = all_queryset.union(subset_queryset, all=True)`

Comment: That's the correct answer! Thanks. Why didn't you put it in the answer section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

union will get an optional parameter `all` which will include duplicate rows as well [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union)

`result_qs = all_queryset.union(subset_queryset, all=True)`